# Android button 2 clicks

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

How to change the android button after 2 clicks ?
the first time to change button i will use this code

```
{
    public void onClick(View v) {
        b.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menubuttonpressed));
    }
}
```

I want to change the button view again after pressing it one more time
how can i do that ?

Comment: Take a counter variable. And increment it every time whenever button is clicked. Check for condition and set your image.

Comment: Keep a global counter than tracks number of clicks. Then do `if(clickCount > 1)   ..Changebutton image`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps do it like this:

```
int count = 0;

public void onClick(View v) {
    count++;

   if(count == 2){
      count = 0;
      b.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                      .getDrawable(R.drawable.menubuttonpressed));
   }
}
```

This will set the background after every 2nd click on your button (view).

Comment: You cannot increment a variable inside onClick function because it has to be a final variable which can't be incremented

Comment: @MohamedNaguib make it global variable then

Comment: @MohamedNaguib: wrong! you can increment. what you are saying may imply in anonymous inner classes and/or threads

Comment: it is supposed to be a global variable - defined outside the **onClick** method

Answer (score 2):

```
private int clickCount =0;

public void onClick(View v) {

    if (clickCount==0) {
        b.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menubuttonpressed));
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
    clickCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, one way is to keep a counter.

```
numberOfClicks = 0;
...
public void onClick(View v) {
  ...
  if(numberOfClicks==0)
    b.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menubuttonpressed0));
  else if(numberofClicks==1)
    b.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menubuttonpressed1));
  ...
  numberofClicks++;
}
```